# "ImportError: No module named site" running NEURON

Tags: python, linux

I have installed Neuron 7.4 and it works well (I ran several simulations of neuron models) and I would like to use it as interpreter of python.

When I type `('$ nrngui -nopython')`, NEURON is launched.
However, when I type `('$ nrngui')`, I obtained the following error:

```
NEURON -- Release 7.4 (1370:16a7055d4a86) 2015-11-09
Duke, Yale, and the BlueBrain Project -- Copyright 1984-2015
See http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/credits

ImportError: No module named site
Py_Initialize exited. PYTHONHOME probably needs to be set correctly.
Our automatic guess based on the Python shared library location:
    export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib
did not work.
It will help to examine the output of:
nrnpyenv.sh
and set the indicated environment variables, or avoid python by adding
nopython: on
to /usr/local/nrn/share/nrn/lib/nrn.defaults (or .nrn.defaults in your $HOME directory)
```

I ran under Debian Jessie 8.10 (x86-64) and my kernel is 3.16.0-5-amd64. I don't that much about debian/linux/jessie environment because I am pretty used to running under Windows.

My final objective is to install LFPy and LFPsim.

Comment: Can you include a link to the instructions you followed to install NEURON?

Comment: Hi, I installed NEURON by following the tutorial on the official website : https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/download 

and for the toolbox LFPy from the website : 

https://senselab.med.yale.edu/ModelDB/FindBySimulator.cshtml

Comment: The error indicates that you need to set the PYTHONHOME environment variable to the location of where python is installed. If you type in "which python" you should be able to get the path to python installation. Then run "export PYTHONHOME=/path/you/got/from/which" to set the variable.

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you cannot use the windows version of NEURON?

Comment: Well my workstation runs under Debian and I successfully installed LFPsim.

Answer (score 1):

I put below my way to install the neuron simulator on a Linux operating system. It works with python without any problems.

First, this works for a version of neuron 7.5 which our lab uses, but note that neuron's developers sometimes update code without changing the number (so call a minor revision). The recipe below works for

```
$nrniv
NEURON -- VERSION 7.5 master (6b4c19f)
```

which I built a year ago, but it may not work for later revisions with a different hash.

Before actual installation, create a machin specific directory in /usr/local and link all directories in /usr/local inside machine specific:

```
$sudo mkdir /usr/local/$(uname -m)
$cd /usr/local/$(uname -m)
$for i in ../bin ../lib ../lib64 ../sbin ../sbin ../share; do ln -s $i ; done
```

if you do not have /usr/local/liv64 directory remove it from for loop and make a link on /usr/local/lib directory: `ln -s ../lib lib64`

If you want to run neuron in parallel install MPI library. I usually use openmpi.
Neuron also wants additional developer package for `ncurses` and `readline`, and X11 libraries for GUI, so all together looks like this:

```
sudo apt install -y \
     libreadline-dev ncurses-dev\ #needed for neuron in general
     libx11-dev libx11-data libice-dev libxcomposite-dev\ # needed for GUI
     openmpi-bin openmpi-common libopenmpi-dev # needed for parallelization
```

Now you can install neuron and iv library if you want to have gui.

Finally, by some unknown reasons, neuron's installer places python modules into `/usr/local/lib/python` directory - which isn't known for anyone but neuron. To make it available for "regular" python I copy all stuff in this directory into `site-packages` directory and then create a link back for nrniv -python command. All together looks like this:

```
$cd /usr/local/lib/python && cp -a * /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$cd /usr/local/lib/ && rm -fR python && ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages python
```

Please use it with a big pinch of salt, because the recipe is a result of some "experiments" and trial-and-error tests.